# Align HTML element to bottom of another HTML element without absolute values

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I have a new problem. I need do a vertical align in a HTML element to bottom of another, but I can use absolute value, one time that the second element can have different height.

Take a look on [**this jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Tu7bA/) please.

The `<a>` need stay on bottom of `<h1>` like [here - workarrounded](http://jsfiddle.net/SVKZ9/).

I tried `vertical-align` but it don't works.

How I can do it? If need, I can change HTML structure without problem.

**Edit**: sorry, but I do not think I left something clear: I can't use `margin-top` or similar, because the `font-size` of `H1` is variable.

Bye.

Comment: can you post the code you are having problems with? it will help others help you better...

Comment: Out of interest, why can't you use absolute values?

Comment: @big The code is on jsFiddle, on post; @tjm Because the `h1` `font-size` is variable. Will depends of selected layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it without having to specify an exact `px` offset like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Tu7bA/14/

**Relevant new CSS:**

```
.header-container {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative
}
.header-container > ul {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0; right: 0
}
.header-container ul > li {
    float: right;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #0A27D5;
    font-size: 8pt;
    margin-left: 16px;
}
.header-container > h1.first {
    float: left;
    font-size: 26pt;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="content-block">
    <div class="header-container">
        <h1 class="first">Lorem Ipsum</h1>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="./Edit">editar</a></li>
            <li><a href="./Attach">anexar</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the corrected code on [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Tu7bA/4/)

Comment: Thanks, but don't works for me. The `a` goes to down of `h1`.

Comment: This is what you have stated in the question? isnt it? its = `"The <a> need stay on bottom of <h1> like here - workarrounded."`

Comment: Sorry, my english don't is too good :) I will up you of gift.

Answer (score 0):

Insert the controls into  element and work with this, for example changing margin-top proprety.

Comment: I can't use margin-top. No absolute values :(

Comment: margin isn't absolute value. Have you try vertical-align proprety ? http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_vertical-align

Comment: i'm sorry for vertical-align :D I've seen now your post.

Comment: you can add invisible div that let you to create space before the second div .

Comment: @arthur can you explain me better about this method?

Comment: If you put <a> and <h1> in a div (container), and above this one you create an invisible(nothing inside) <div> ; your <div> will be move below. If wou want that your div has different size according to font-size you can use js for resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

`vertical-align` doesn't work because it only aligns itself in its area, which is below `h1`. So, here:

```
div.content-block > a {
float: right;
text-decoration: none;
color: #0A27D5;
font-size: 8pt;
margin-left: 16px;
}
```

Add `margin-top:<value>` to push it a little down, say

```
div.content-block > a {
float: right;
text-decoration: none;
color: #0A27D5;
font-size: 8pt;
margin-left: 16px;
margin-top: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is fine [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QyG6W/).Hope it helps